# Can't Access Parent Component variable in Child Component - Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a variable named LoginResponse which stores the response I get from the server after I login. I redirect the app to dashboard on successful login.
I wish to access LoginResponse in my Dashboard.component.ts

LOGIN FUNCTION IN APP COMP-

```
    onLogin(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(form);
    this.serverService.Login(JSON.stringify(form.value))
      .subscribe(
        (response) => { 
        form.reset();
        this.LoginResponse = response.json().data;
        jQuery(this.modalcloser.nativeElement).modal('hide'); 
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        console.log(this.LoginResponse);
        },
        (error) => {console.log(error.json()),
     jQuery(this.modalcloser.nativeElement).modal('hide'); 
     jQuery(this.errormodal.nativeElement).modal('show'); 
         this.errormsg = (error.json().error);
    }
   );
  }
```

DASHBOARD COMP-

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  @Input() LoginResponse: {token: string, teamname: string, member1name: string, member2name: string, member3name: string };

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.LoginResponse);
  }

  // logOut() {
  //    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  // }

}
```

APP DIRECTORY-
[image]

Comment: how does your dashboard component in html on parent?

Comment: Added screenshot in OP. @Sajeetharan

Comment: not the directory , how you have passed the value in html. paste the code of parent component

Comment: LoginResponse isn't displayed anywhere in parent component html. I only wish to display it in Dashboard component

Comment: you need to use dashboardcomponent inside the html of parentcomponent and pass as input, otherwise it wont work

Comment: Isnt there any way to communicate between components and share variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the above implementation of event-emitter, your parent component should have

```
<app-dashboard [LoginResponse]="LoginResponse"></app-dashboard>
```

**2nd way:**
You can share variables across components using  a service that keeps the state and all child component subscribe to the state and parent.

```
@Injectable()
export class sharedService {
 LoginResponse:any;
 constructor() {
}
 Initialize() {
    this.LoginResponse = assign value here;
}

 get() {
    return this.LoginResponse;
 }
}
```

Then in DASHBOARD.ts

```
import { sharedService } from '/services/sharedService.service';
 constructor( private sharedSer : sharedService ) {

    }

Update(){
  this.LoginResponse = this.sharedSer.get();
}
```

Comment: can you demonstrate how can i do that? that will be a great help!

Comment: the above one should help

Answer (score 0):

In your app.component.html, inject dashboard component like below:

```
 <app-dashboard [LoginResponse]="LoginResponse"></app-dashboard>
```